# place background image outside of a <table> <td> <tr> borders in embedded html mail

Tags: html, css, html-email

Looking through some html email examples, I noticed is all about tables. I wanted an image inside of one of the rows of the main table to look like half of the image is outside the table and the other half inside. I can't get the solution to do that.

Any helps would be appreciated, really appreciated
Here's is what I like.

[image]
The orange thin line would be the table border
I got it working int the webpage where I can use divs and a lot of stylesheet but in html embedded in email haven't found the way. As you can see there's text and images above the image

Answer (score 1):

Here, I managed to create a simple example:

```
 +--------+--------+--------+
 | TEXT GOES HERE  |        |
 |                 | empty  |
 |                 |        |
 |        +--------+--------+
 |        |                 |
 |        | IMAGE GOES HERE |
 |        |                 |
 +--------+-----------------+
```

What you're basically doing is:

- Create a table with three columns (actually there are only 2 `<td>`s)
- For text: Use `<td colspan="2">text</td> <td></td>`
- For an image: Use `<td>maybe text here</td> <td colspan="2"> <img/> </td>`

[**Live example on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dNHMB/1/) (updated, it includes borders now)

Comment: Actually I changed the question to show what i'm looking for. In your image the image should be outside the border of the whole table

Comment: now it looks's similar to what I want. Is it possible to add some text and button above the image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this can't be done: A background image will span only as far as the element it is in, no further.

You may be able to do something with a huge, invisible cell that makes your table extend beyond the visible data.

Comment: I'm sure this can be done playing with different widths and heights of tables nested in tables, but it would be pretty annoying after all...

Comment: Could I create a div outside of the table and moving it to where I want it. And the things that should look above of the image setting a z-index 2?